Laravel - Validate input body is a list
I'm trying to write a validation in Laravel 11 for a POST call which passes a list of objects like this
[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]
All documentation I've found explains how to validate a list if it's a sub-object, as {"list": [{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]}, but this api expects the data root to be the list, invalidating this attempts.

You can pass a closure as a validation rule and do whatever you want in there:
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'your_param' => [
            'required',
            function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) {
                if ($value === 'foo') {
                    $fail("The {$attribute} is invalid.");
                }
            },
        ]
    ]
}

see more: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#using-closures
Or, a more testable and neater way would be to write a custom Rule class

I kinda understand, but your_param still needs a name, don't? Can I have
=> ['required', <closure>]
]```
?

The point is, the list is the root, there isn't anything indexing it

ah yep, you may be able to use * so return ['*' => function(blah)] which means "every param that comes in must pass this function test". I don't know if you can 'required' a '*' though.
